# Italic text can be caused unintentionally in comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown

Example: "void*" becomes *void* (the asterisk is lost). See my comment on Nicholaz's response on [Ignore "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763616/ignore-initialization-from-incompatible-pointer-type-warnings)

Comment: Er.. no it doesn't! Try typing void* or "void*"

Comment: Really @Jeff? Just now catching up to one-year-old posts? :) (what a backlog you must have!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig is right, but his answer doesn't escape the backticks.  He generated his answer:

`void*`

, by doing this:

```
`void*`
```

I know it's a minor thing to complain about, but he does say "surround it ... like this," and the question is already about how to use Markdown.

Incidentally, I made the backticks show up in my answer by putting HTML `pre` tags around them, like this:

```
<pre>`void*`</pre>
```

Comment: Except that I don't see any backticks. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how do I edit my comment?

Comment: Interesting.  They showed up in the preview box but not the actual post.  I think I saw a meta post about that a few days ago.  Stand by...

Comment: @timn, unfortunately, you can't edit comments.  The best you can do is copy the comment to your clipboard, delete the comment and post a new one with the fix.

Comment: @Cigars, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view shows status-deferred.  That's the first time it's happened to me.

Comment: @Cigars, I edited the post to avoid that problem altogether.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: You can use &gt; and &lt; if you want to use them in tags. Or you could also wrap them in a <pre>.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: I actually had to look at one of Jeff's recent posts to see exactly how to make it work. (pre tags to the rescue!) I'd been fruitlessly trying to edit your for about 5 minutes ... Saw the answer after I commented and just said the heck with it. :) Thanks for fixing it, though.

Comment: And I took care of the HTML piece at the end of your post for you.

Comment: @Cigars, thanks.  I thought about fixing the HTML myself but kind of decided it wasn't worth the additional time input anymore.

Answer (score 10):

When you put code in a comment, surround it with backticks (`), like this:

`void*`

Then it will be formatted like code and won't apply Markdown.

Comment: You mean like `this*`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use backticks. You can use a backslash to escape asterisk.

```
void\*
```

Comment: Test with no backslashes: *(void*) foo. Test with backslashes: \*(void\*) foo.