# How to display mutliple literal backticks in a paragraph outside of inline code

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown

I have an exception which contains backtick (`) characters.  I can't find a way to escape the character from markdown so that I can show the message as normal text.

Exception marked as inline code with double backticks to preserve the singles in the content:
`` Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__61`4[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'. ``

What happens if I don't do the above (markdown treats two of the three backicks as formatting commands):
Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__61`4[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

Comment: Related: [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me a few days back.  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30345/bug-italic-text-caused-unintentionally-in-comments/30362#30362) and its comments.

I think the short answer was to choose between using `<pre>` tags or escaping the backticks with backslashes.

Here are some backticks in text with pre:

````
blahblahblah```foobar
````

Here are some backticks in memes with backslashes (it turns out this is another case of displays-right-in-preview-box-but-not-reality):
freehand circles```waffles!

Markdown for using pre:
<pre>blahblahblah```foobar</pre>

Comment: But if you use `<pre>`, you have to escape angle brackets.

Comment: Thanks.  I could've sworn I tried escaping them before posting this though.  Maybe I tried using the wrong slash..

Answer (score 1):

You could format it as a code block:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__61`4[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.
```

Although admittedly, with a single long line like this, it's not very easy to read.

Comment: Yeah.  Making it inline code so that I at least got to keep the word wrapping was the least unpleasant option I could find.