# How can the backtick character ` be included in code?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, character-escaping

I tried before to post a shell script that contained a ` character as an answer on Stack Overflow. The parser insisted on treating the backtick as formatting instead of part of code.

How can I include it?

Comment: You can use the HTML entity `&#96;`.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

If you do not want to use a [pre-formatted block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/inclusion-of-the-backtick-character-as-part-of-code/55439#55439), there is still a way to do it inline.

From the [“Code” section of the Markdown Documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:
>
> ```
> ``There is a literal backtick (`) here.``
> ```

The above example renders like this (double quotes added): “`` There is a literal backtick (`) here. ``”

Also of note, you can add spaces to render an inline code segment that starts with and/or ends with backticks:

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:
>
> ```
> A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``
> A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``
> ```

The above examples render like this (quotes added): “A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``” and “A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``”.

---

This may be implementation specific, but it looks like you can use N backticks to delimit any inline sequence that does not itself contain a maximal subsequence of exactly N backticks. For example, you can use three backticks to delimit a sequence that does not contain triple backticks (single, double, quadruple, quintuple, etc. are okay though).

`````
Three quoting one, two and four:  ``` one: `  two:   ``  four: ```` ```
Two quoting one, three, and four: ``  one: `  three: ``` four: ```` ``
One quoting two, three and four:  `   two: `` three: ``` four: ```` `
`````

Yields:

Three quoting one, two and four:  ````` one: `  two:   ``  four: ```` `````
Two quoting one, three, and four: ````` one: `  three: ``` four: ```` `````
One quoting two, three and four:  ````` two: `` three: ``` four: ```` `````

---

Finally, for comments:

```
Ah, in comments one does need to escape using a backslash? `\`yes\``.
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, at least, ``double ` work in comments``.

Comment: Ah, you're right @Mark, using a unique number of multiple opening and closing backticks works in comments too nowadays: `\`\`one \` or three \`\`\` within double backticks\`\`` nicely yields ``one ` or three ``` within double backticks``. But in comments, it still doesn't work when adding a space to the delimiters, to allow for a backtick at the start or end of the code. Like to get Perl's `$\`` it seems one needs `\`$\\`\`` in comments, as `\`\` $\` \`\`` yields `` $` ``.

Comment: ([Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mTgja.png) of the above comment, for future reference, as comments are rendered on the fly. So: if the implementation is changed, the above comment might render differently some day in the future.)

Comment: Uau, costed me a bit to the the gist of the thing, dam ticks :)

Comment: Is a trailing backtick not possible? You can see that this does not get formatted: ```kill `pidof chrome````

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Try putting a space between the trailing backtick and the closing backticks: `\`\`\`kill \`pidof chrome\` \`\`\``

Comment: upvote for the escaping note for comments.

Answer (score 46):

[ChrisF's solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/inclusion-of-the-backtick-character-as-part-of-code/55439#55439) is the cleanest and easiest method, so I recommend using that whenever you can.

But if you find yourself needing it for inline code text and can tolerate needing to use `<code>` tags, its HTML entity `&#96;`, demonstrated here: `<code>this &#96; is a backtick</code>` renders as `` this ` is a backtick ``.

Comment: This works, but **only in _answers_, not in comments** (where inline HTML is not supported). However (at least as of this writing), **just use `\`` (backticks) _directly_ inside `<code>` elements** - no need to resort to HTML entities.

Comment: Interestingly, `&grave;` _doesn't_ work.

Comment: This worked flawlessy in WordPress, unlike double-backticks from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

Put the code on a separate line and indent by 4 characters.

```
Like ` this
```

Answer (score 15):

To show a single backtick formatted as inline code, there are three options:

- ``` `` ` `` ``` (Opening and closing the code section with 2 or more backticks)
- `<code>&#96</code>`
- `` <code>`</code> ``

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: None of this 3 solutions worked for me when writing a code inline with backticks as an answer. The only solution was to put it in a new line and indented as in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55439/779583

Answer (score 0):

I needed to display the following on Stack Overflow: [image]

Using a double backtick to escape the entire sequence does not work:

``x```

I could almost get it to work by adding a space before the closing pair:

`` x` ``

but that wasn't quite right. I ended up using a `<code>` block:

`` x` ``

Also, as suggested by @Laurel, you can add spaces both before and after:

`` x` ``

Comment: I wonder if you can use spaces on either side: `` x` ``. (Apparently not in comments).

Comment: @Laurel well done!