# How do I render a backtick enclosed in <kbd> tags?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering, backtick

The following line of Markdown isn't rendered the way I expect:

```
Press the <kbd>`</kbd> key then type ``foo bar baz``.
```

The actual HTML being rendered omits the `<kbd>` tags:

```
Press the  ` key then type <code>foo bar baz</code>.
```

However, what I want is the following HTML:

```
Press the <kbd>`</kbd> key then type <code>foo bar baz</code>.
```

I've tried various combinations of [escaping the backtick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-to-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown) and using `<code>` instead of `` ` ``, to no avail. How do I get the effect I want?

(The post in question is [over here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97616/274).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you linked isn't formatted properly as HTML:

```
Press  <kbd>`<kbd> to open the console, click on the NPC, and type <code>SetEssential 0</code>.
```

Notice the lack of `/` in the closing tag.

The Markdown processor works as expected:

> Press the <kbd>`</kbd> key then type `foo bar baz`.

Comment: (and then you can slash-escape the first backtick to avoid having to use `<code></code>`)

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. Can I blame the egg nog? Is it too late to blame egg nog?