# How do I post Markdown code in a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I have a question about some Markdown code not displaying as expected that I would like to ask on Stack Overflow. If I add the code (which includes triple-back-ticks), it is obviously rendered as an HTML code block in the displayed question. I tried to escape the back-ticks with "\" so that they would display, which works, but I get an error message, "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by four spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.".

The error message prevents me from posting the question. How can I include Markdown code in a question?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly you’ve tried to do? Have you read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/289905)?

Comment: Have you considered using an online Markdown editor that would host your code?

Comment: @avazula Using only CodePen would cause a different error and would otherwise quickly be closed as off-topic due to lack of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you could also start your markdown with a code fence by starting with three ``` on a line by itself and at the end of the markdown block three ``` on a line by itself.

Comment: @rene it sounds like the code they're trying to post includes triple back-ticks, which is the problem: "*If I add the code (which includes triple-back-ticks), it is obviously rendered as an html code block*"

Comment: Welcome to Meta! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape a backtick \` within in-line code in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-within-in-line-code-in-markdown) --- This is also useful info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code contains triple backticks, you have a few options:

- Use more than 3 backticks on your main code block.
- Use 3 or more tildes (`~`) on your main code block
- Indent all the code lines by 4 spaces.

Examples (view source to see how I did them):

````
This codeblock was made with 5 backticks instead of 3
```
and it works
```
````

````
This codeblock was made with 3 tildes
```
and it works
```
````

````
This codeblock is indented by 4 spaces
```
and it works
```
````

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I put a 4 back-tick block around the 3 back-tick block which then displays the 3 back-ticks around the code.