Escaping a backtick with a backslash in backtick-delimited inline code seems to be broken
In the comments, you can use
`\``

to escape a (code formatted) backtick, like so:



resulting in



However, in question (and answer) posts, it doesn't work. It ends up looking like three backticks: ```.
To get what you want you have to use <code>...</.code>, or least that is how I worked around the issue:
<code>`</code>

which gives: `

I doubt a single backslash ever worked: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347313

Oh right, I hadn't seen that. Well, that's a shame. Thanks.

That would be yet another deviation of comment Markdown from CommonMark. You are supposed to write \` ` ``. But in comment Markdown this results in ``  ``.
