# <code> formatting bug with ` within the code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

When marking text as a code with `<code>` tag, it doesn't work properly with code containing `` ` ``. 
Following two lines should look the same:

```
<pre>code `sample`</pre>

<code>code `sample`</code>
```

but display:

```
code `sample`
```

`code sample`

Why isn't indentation/`<pre>` a solution? Because you cannot use it to mark inline code (like the one in this and previous sentence), for which you have to use `<code>` or ``` `` ```.

---

As for Cody's "solution" with using only markdown:

1. type a text containing single back-tick somewhere in the middle
2. mark part of the text
3. click `{}` button
4. result is **not** correct: `"and example with` back-tick in it"`

---

There is second related bug, this produces unexpected  behaviour:

```
<code>`</code> <code>`sample`</code>
```

is shown as

`` </code> <code>sample` ``

Comment: They look the same to me - except for the backticks.

Comment: I think it works as designed; if you need to use backticks, you can indent the code with four spaces. If I recall it correctly, the syntax highlighting is handled by [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: @pavium That is what @vartec is reporting: the backticks should be escaped in the second line, as they are in the first one.

Comment: I see you've updated your question with some more "bugs". The problem is, you're mixing and matching formatting styles: HTML tags and Markdown. That's not supported. Pick one and stick with it. There are no notable limitations on how you can express yourself (and your code snippets) with the Markdown formatting that's allowed.

Comment: @Cody: hmm.. http://my.opera.com/freejerk/homes/files/bug-feature.jpg

Comment: I didn't say it was a feature...

Comment: You did say that `{}` toolbar button works. Care to comment the 4 step example I gave?

Comment: Can't repro that 4 step example. I've tried it multiple times. I get exactly the same result as when I type in text with a backtick that's intended 4 spaces. Coincidentally enough, that's all the toolbar button does. It indents each line by 4 spaces. The UI isn't *that* hard to use...

Comment: @Cody: Updated, you're getting indent, because you're marking whole line. It's not a question if UI is hard or not, it's the question that it doesn't work correctly. I think you're just trolling, because you know perfectly that you couldn't get format for that single backtick example in your answer just using the UI.

Comment: Disagree. Still works fine for me. I guess I'm clicking the button in the right spot.

Comment: @Cody: yeah, and I'm probably holding it wrong too... You can take a look of source of my question if you cannot mark part in the middle of the text and click {}

Comment: @Cody: What vartec means is that you can use the `{}` toolbar button _both_ for marking code blocks (indented by 4 spaces) and for marking inline code with backticks (pretty fancy and very useful). The latter, namely inline code marking, happens if _less than one line_ is highlighted. Now vartec's complaint is: If you have `my foo \` bar` on a line, highlight `foo \` bar` and hit the code button, you will _not_ get `my ``foo \` bar\`\``, but only single backticks, and that won't give the desired code formatting.

Answer (score 5):

There's a reason you aren't supposed to use the `<code>` tag when Markdown will work just as well. HTML tags should only be substituted for things that Markdown syntax doesn't natively support. In this case, of course, code formatting is fully supported, all you have to do is indent the line with 4 spaces, or use the handy toolbar button:

[image: Code Formatting button on the toolbar]

The result looks exactly as you would expect:

```
code `sample`    // Markdown syntax, indented with 4 spaces
```

I wouldn't waste any time "fixing" this. You also don't get syntax highlighting with HTML tags, another reason to prefer the Markdown syntax.

---

> so if you're saying that `<code>` is not necessary, how would you write inline code containing ``?

It works just fine for me: ``` Here's some inline code with `` backticks ```

And by special request: `` Here's some inline code with ` a single inline backtick ``

For more tips, please see the related question: [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)

Comment: Try to write first sentence of your answer preserving the formatting, but not using neither `<code>` nor ``.

Comment: @vartec: Why? It'd be awfully hard to write it without a keyboard, too. That's what they're here for.

Comment: @Cody: so if you're saying that `<code>` is not necessary, how would you write inline code containing ``?

Comment: @vartec: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code

Comment: @vartec: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code Works just fine for me.

Comment: @Cody: It's a bit strange that you write "you aren't supposed to use the `<code>` tag". Then why is it implemented that you _can_ use it?

Comment: @Hendrik: There's a difference between things that you're *allowed* to do and things that you're *supposed* to do. It's allowed because it's essentially harmless, just like the `<b>` tag. But there's absolutely no point, since Markdown syntax provides a superior alternative. In this case, the alternative's superiority is even more noticeable, as you get syntax highlighting if you use the Markdown syntax, but not with the HTML tags.

Comment: @Cody: can you also show it working fine with unmatched backticks?

Comment: @vartec: Done. Did you read the [link I referenced in a previous comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)?

Comment: @Cody: OK, so maybe it should say "you aren't supposed to use the `<code>` tag _unless you know what you're doing_". `<code>` does have it's uses as I explain in [the answer to the question behind the link in a previous comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Comment: @Hendrik: Perhaps so. I'm merely answering here from experience: I've answered a lot of questions and left a lot of comments with code, both inline and in block form, and I've never had an occasion where I need to use it. It's possible that TeX has different requirements than SO. My point is more "don't use the `<code>` tag when Markdown works just as well for your purposes".

Comment: @Cody: I agree with that last point 100%.

Comment: @Cody: FAQ says otherwise, `<code>` is valid way to mark code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @vartec: Erm, what part of that contradicts *anything* I've said in my answer? I've given you multiple possible solutions to your problem, and a developer has already marked this question with the `status-bydesign` tag. I'm not sure what more you're wanting here except to be argumentative. I'm not terribly interested in that. I didn't write the FAQ, and I'm not a developer on the site. Pick a fight with one of them.

Comment: @Cody: FAQ contradicts part of answer, where you say: "you aren't supposed to use the `<code>`"

Comment: @vartec: The FAQ is a community contribution. Not everything it says is gospel. You obviously have to take things with a grain of salt if they don't work. It says all over the site that Markdown formatting is preferred. Really, you could have answered this question yourself by simply consulting the formatting tips sidebar that appears each time you ask a question (or the tips that appear when you write a comment). None of them say anything about the `<code>` tag. We've given you a second option, and now you're complaining that it's not as good as the first. Well, duh.

Comment: @Cody: first of all, you should check before you make claim that anything about double backtick escaping is included in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help, second side contains link to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user which again states that users are free to use HTML

Comment: @vartec: You're free to use it. It's not guaranteed to work. Markdown is the preferred alternative. You're only supposed to use HTML tags when Markdown doesn't work. Are you really not getting this, or just playing dumb? As I said before: **We've given you a second option, and now you're complaining that it's not as good as the first. Well, duh.** You can also use an onscreen keyboard to type everything in using the mouse. But please don't file a bug report that's it not as good as a keyboard.

Comment: @Cody: show me "It's not guaranteed to work." in the FAQ.

Comment: @vartec: Yeah, not everything is in the FAQ. If it was, this site wouldn't have much of a purpose. What are you upset about? I didn't say "you asked a bad question". I said "you now have your answer". You want this added to the FAQ? It's a wiki, edit it yourself now that you know. I mean, come on. Have you noticed that the `<code>` and `<pre>` tags don't have syntax highlighting applied to them? Or did I just spoil the punch to the next question you were going to ask.

Comment: @Cody: I won't add to a wiki something with which I completely disagree. If `<code>` is supported (and it clearly is), then is should work as expected. Unexpected behaviour is bug, not a feature.