# How do I escape a backtick ` character?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)

I was answering a question on bash script in which is ` is included twice in answer.

How can I escape default behavior of ` on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is one chasing you?