# Escaping backtick

Tags: support, code-formatting, character-escaping

How can I escape a backtick?

I've tried whatever is written in the "How to Format" rubric that's on the right of the page, but it didn't work:
`like _so_`

I want the backtick to be written in a comment (This is why a code block isn't a solution)

Thank you.

**Edit #1 (12:04 UTC):**

By using CodeCaster's answer, I've managed to escape a backtick.
But a funny thing happens when using the following two examples:

First example:

Code:

```
`like _so_\``
```

Result:
`like *so*``

Second Example:

Code:

```
``like _so_\`
```

Result:
``like *so*`

Comment: `\\`like _so_\\`` = \`like _so_\` ??

Comment: Correct answer: The documented solution (somewhere) is to double the ``starting ` and ending ` ``. And if you wanted ``` `` ```, you triplicate them, etc.

So to mention ```` Three ```, two `` and one ` I need four ` at each end ````.

(I've flagged to allow my answer to be added.) (Obviously this isn't correct in comments, except for just duplicates!)

Comment: @Mark Hurd: That works great thanks!

Comment: Here's an answer that is a duplicate for the original question: [How can the backtick character ` be included in code?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70679/147650)

Comment: Hmmm you can see above double backquotes worked and then triple, etc. did not in that comment, but when I tried to mention that as a comment to the answer I've linked to above it didn't work :-( Trying again here: ``Double ` work sometimes in comments`` and seeing as it worked again here I successfully added a comment there too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70679/147650) you double the `` starting ` and ending ` ``.

And if you wanted ``` `` ```, you triplicate them, etc. So to mention ```` Three ```, two `` and one ` I need four ` at each end ````.

But only double backticks work in comments, and they're slightly flakey there.

Answer (score 7):

Put a backslash in front of it:

`this is not inline`.

Comment: `\`` test comment

Answer (score 1):

If all your inline code is a single backtick, this only works for comments:

```
`\``
```

On posts, you need to double the opening and closing backticks, and surround the middle one with spaces. So:

```
`` ` ``
```

Output of the above: `` ` ``