# How to escape backtick inside backticks?

Tags: support, comments

Suppose the following chunk of code:

```
lines = text.split`\n`
```

<sup>Not relevant, but it is valid ES6 code</sup>

My question is: How to write it inside one comment? When I use backticks around content it displays the content formatted as code. But what if there are backticks inside this content?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Backslashes should do it. e.g.:

```
`lines = text.split\`\n\``
```

will produce the same formatting in a comment as you have in your question.

Comment: I think the OP might've meant meant inline code, not a comment. Doesn't seem to work there. (Or maybe I'm trying too hard to read things into the question.)

Comment: @Jefromi Hmm. Yeah, that seems to be busted. I thought multiple backticks would work there, but in testing it... guess not.

Comment: Ah, and there is a super-old dup for the inline version: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code - open and close with multiple backticks; that seems to work in comments too.

Comment: @Jefromi Aha, that's what I was thinking of. Thanks for digging it up.